# Send Response to all active session when database data changes

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to send a response to all users which are currently active (Logged or viewing content) when the database data changes.

**Example**

Some user is viewing "data" table.

Currently I'm executing AJAX calls every 5 seconds and if there is change in data database response the client will be notified.

However I no longer want to do it this way.

Comment: `but now i don't want to do this way.` what?

Comment: is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: you could read about long polling or websockets to avoid "reloads" every 5 (xy) seconds.

Comment: No, there is no other way, you need to make the request every X seconds, your database can't do that by itself.

Comment: @djot i did not get what you said

Comment: yea i know database can/t do automatic but i want to do this using php or ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative for ajax polling (as you did) is using comet/server-side push.

In other words, you would use something like WebSockets, Ajax long-polling, Server-Sent Events, etc., to send messages to the client instead of the client polling.

For the sake of this example, I'm going to use WebSockets. What I describe below applies to the other methods as well, though.

If you already have an existing PHP application, the simplest way to do this would probably be to write a separate "daemon" script which handles the sockets. Whenever your application changes some data in the DB, you would send a message to the daemon script, which would then notify the connected clients of the change.

You could use something like ZeroMQ for messaging between the main app and the socket daemon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use polling or websockets, maybe [Pusher.com](http://pusher.com/) is a solution for you.